# Puzzle regarding emptying of cup!

Tags: number-theory

Initially, I have $3$ cups with infinite capacity and some prefilled amount of water(positive integers). I can do only one operation repeatedly by choosing any $2$ out of $3$. The operation is that if you have $2$ cups with volume $a$ and $b$ and $a <= b$, then the operation changes the volume as $b-a$, $2*a$. Basically, it pours the liquid from the more filled cup to the less filled cup by the same amount that it had initially. My goal is to empty any $1$ cup and see if it is possible for all initial cases. Now, if I had $2$ cups, the answer turns out to be that if the sum of the volumes of the cups is of the form $2^N$, then $1$ of the cups will eventually become empty, otherwise, it gets stuck in a loop. I need to generalize this to $3$ cups. Also, you can factor out gcd of the numbers in the beginning as that will remain constant.

Comment: @RishabhJain, it's the *integer* part I was mainly asking about. Actually all that matters is that the *ratios* of the prefilled amounts, one to the other, are *rational* (since after that you can pick a measurement scale, e.g., grams, drams, ounces, or whatever, to make the amounts all integers).

Comment: Someone at puzzle stack exchange was able to solve this puzzle. You can check out the solution at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104571/puzzle-regarding-emptying-of-cup/104630#104630